# How to fetch from SSH git repo in LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

I have a repo in GitHub Enterprise, for the sake of example, domain is "myserver" and repo is name "myrepo". The remote is set up with SSH, so the remote url looks like: `git@myserver/myrepo.git`. I wrote a method using LibGit2Sharp as follows:

```
using LibGit2Sharp; // LibGit2Sharp Version 0.26.2 with LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries Version 2.0.306

    public static void Fetch(string repoFolder, string remoteName, string branchName=null)
    {
        using (var repo = new Repository(repoFolder))
        {
            var remote = repo.Network.Remotes.Single(r => r.Name == remoteName).Url;

            var branch = repo.Branches.Single(b => b.IsRemote && b.RemoteName == remoteName && b.FriendlyName == $"{remoteName}/{branchName ?? "master"}");

            repo.Network.Fetch(remote, new [] {branch.CanonicalName} );
        }
    }
```

When I run it, the `Network.Fetch` method throws a `LibGit2Sharp.InvalidSpecificationException` with a message as follows:

`'git@myserver/myrepo.git' is not a valid remote name.`

How do I specify the remote when it is secured using SSH?

Comment: use FetchOptions and set CredentialProvider property.

Comment: I am guessing the fetch command is looking for a remote name (like origin), so that is not a valid remote. You need to add a remote first (using the ssh uri), and then you can fetch from there.